# Slide up an input field

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

When my button is getting hovered, I want to slide up a new input field, so that it would look like it came from behind the button.

First, I was trying to make this only using CSS. Therefore I tried to work with the surrounded form height, using `overflow: hidden`. 
But when I do so, the button gets faded out instead of the input field. Is there any way to change this? Like a specific browser thingy?
So much for that.

Now I tried to work with jQuery, but I'm not used to do it. I really hope you got an idea to make it work correctly.

The value which needs to be changed is **margin**: `0 auto -3px` to `0 auto -31px`

Here is my [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ELqzF/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done without javascript if you create a surrounding div.

I have created a div with a class of "some" (in lack of creativity). Then when you hover it, the input field becomes visible.

css:

```
.some {
    display: inline-block;
}

.some:hover .l-input {
    margin: 0 auto -3px; 
}

.l-button {
    text-transform: uppercase;
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
width: 7em;
position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
 }

.l-input {
margin: 0 auto -31px;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
width: 5.9em;
position: relative;
height: 1.25em;
    display: block;
 }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c3Veu/

edit:

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/sbNym/

Used absolute position instead, so the input field pops up from behind. (:

Comment: it works. thanks for that. but the button needs to stay. not the inpout field. any idea?

Comment: Check the new fiddle (:

Answer (score 0):

try this `HTML`:

```
    <div id="container">
        <input type="text" name="bewerbung" class="l-input">
        <button type="button" value="BSend" class="l-button">code</button>
    </div>
```

and this `Script`:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('.l-button').mouseover(function () {
                $('.l-input').animate({ bottom: '40px' });
            });
            $('.l-input').mouseleave(function () {
                $('.l-input').animate({ bottom: '6px' });
            });
        });
```

and this `CSS`:

```
        body {
            padding: 5em;
        }

        /*NEW*/
        #container {
            position: relative;
            width: 90px;
        }
        /*NEW*/

        input {
            background: transparent;
            border: 1px solid rgba(155,86,77,0.2);
            border-width: 0 0 1px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
            -moz-border-radius: 3px;
            -o-border-radius: 3px;
            border-radius: 3px;
            padding: 5px;
            background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.1) 100%);
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0.1)));
            background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.1) 100%);
            background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.1) 100%);
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.1) 100%);
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.1) 100%);
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1a000000', endColorstr='#1affffff',GradientType=0 );
            -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset, -1px -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.2) inset, -1px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset, 0 3px 0 rgba(155,86,77,0.8);
            -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset, -1px -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.2) inset, -1px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset, 0 3px 0 rgba(155,86,77,0.8);
            -ms-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset, -1px -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.2) inset, -1px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset, 0 3px 0 rgba(155,86,77,0.8);
            -o-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset, -1px -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.2) inset, -1px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset, 0 3px 0 rgba(155,86,77,0.8);
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset, -1px -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.2) inset, -1px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset, 0 3px 0 rgba(155,86,77,0.8);
            font-family: Raleway;
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            -moz-appearance: none;
            appearance: none;
            outline: none;
            -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
            -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
            -webkit-tap-highlight: none;
            -webkit-focus-ring-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
            -webkit-focus-ring-color: transparent;
            -webkit-focus-ring-color: none;
        }

        .l-input:active, .l-input:focus {
            -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset, -1px -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.2) inset, -1px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset, 0 0 1px 4px rgba(105,157,182,0.3), 0 4px 0 rgba(155,86,77,0.8);
            -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset, -1px -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.2) inset, -1px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset, 0 0 1px 4px rgba(105,157,182,0.3), 0 4px 0 rgba(155,86,77,0.8);
            -ms-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset, -1px -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.2) inset, -1px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset, 0 0 1px 4px rgba(105,157,182,0.3), 0 4px 0 rgba(155,86,77,0.8);
            -o-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset, -1px -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.2) inset, -1px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset, 0 0 1px 4px rgba(105,157,182,0.3), 0 4px 0 rgba(155,86,77,0.8);
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset, -1px -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.2) inset, -1px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset, 0 0 1px 4px rgba(105,157,182,0.3), 0 4px 0 rgba(155,86,77,0.8);
        }

        button {
            display: inline-block;
            color: #FFF;
            background: #699DB6;
            padding: 7px 20px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
            border-bottom-width: 3px;
        }

        .l-button {
            text-transform: uppercase;
            margin: 0 auto;
            display: block;
            width: 7em;
            position: relative;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .l-input {
            margin: 0 auto -3px;
            text-align: center;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            width: 5.9em;
            position: absolute;            /*NEW*/
            bottom: 6px;            /*NEW*/
            height: 1.25em;
            display: block;
        }
```

Comment: your answer helped me alot. i got one little problem left. because im using .load to load in my sites, i had to use $(document).on('mouseleave', '.l-button', function () { but when i do, the client is not ablte to fill in something because it gets too quickly out. it is possible to make it stay when the inout field is hovered too?